# Why it is not sufficient to show $I_n\neq [A,B]$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Use $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$ to show that the identity matrix $I_n$ is not contained in the span of the set $\{[A,B]|A,B\in M_{n\times n}(K)\}$. Note that it is not sufficient to show that $I_n\neq [A,B]$ for any pair $A,B$ of $n\times n$ matrices
(8 pts).

I know how to prove the problem. But why it’s not sufficient?

I’m not sure if my following proof is correct. 
For any $A,B$, $tr([A,B])=tr(AB)-tr(BA)=0\neq n =tr(I_n)$. 
Thus $I_n\neq [A,B]$.

I think it’s sufficient to prove the problem.

Comment: Because maybe it is the linear combination of several $[A_i,B_i]$'s? It's generally not the case that $[A,B]+[C,D]$ is $[A',B']$ for some $A'$ and  $B'$.

Comment: What is $tr$? ${}$

Comment: The problem is asking about the _span_. If $[A,B]\ne I$, for all pairs $A,B$, that doesn't, in and of itself, prove that $I$ is not in the span (the set of linear combinations) of all such $[A,B]$.

Comment: Look for example at the matrices $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0& 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}5& 0\\ 0& 0\end{pmatrix}$. While neither one is $I_2$, you can still write $I_2$ as a linear combination of these two matrices.